# Python Traceback error in facebuilder plugin

Tags: modeling, python, texturing, sculpting

I added the Facebuilder feature and made a face as a test, but I'm getting this error when adding Texture. What is the solution. Blender version 3.0

[image]

Comment: That's a third-party addon, not part of Blender. See if the [FAQs down the page here](https://keentools.io/download/facebuilder-for-blender) help. Otherwise you'll have to contact the author.

Comment: Was it made for 3.0 specifically ?